# Adding a sterling symbol to a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols

Again this may be really obvious but how can I add a sterling sign to a ggplot?

I've been trying

```
ylab(expression(symbol('\U00a3')))
```

in e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1:10,1:10,geom='line')+ylab(expression(symbol('\U00a3')))
```

but I get a romanized R instead.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: hi @e4e5f4 I'm using linux ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`symbol` looks up the Adobe Symbol encoding, whereas you want to use an escaped unicode character. Therefore do not use `expression(symbol('\U00a3'))`. There is no sterling sign in the Adobe Symbol encoding (but you could for instance get a Euro sign using `expression(symbol('\240'))` ).

I cannot easily tell you why `expression(symbol('\U00a3'))` returns the `Rfraktur` and the `lessequal` sign though. Interestingly the symbol code for `lessequal` is `'\243'`, which is also the code the the sterling sign in the Adobe Latin encoding. `Rfraktur` is given by `'\302'`.

To get a sterling sign use this:

```
qplot(1:10,1:10,geom='line')+ylab('\U00a3')
```

[image]

Or you could use

```
qplot(1:10,1:10,geom='line')+ylab(expression('\U00a3'))
```

Which will do the same thing.

Comment: You don't need `paste` either